# The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure. Unable to translate Unicode character \uDB08 at index 372 to specified code page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Please I need assistance figuring out what is going on with my Visual Studio setup (Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop.

Each time I try to run this Hello World code in C#(below) I get a "Error 1 The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDB08 at index 372 to specified code page" (Please see below for full error message).

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio with no sucess. I'd really appreciate someone's help. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```

....Error Message starts here.....

Error 1 The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDB08 at index 372 to specified code page.
   at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.SendData(INodePacket packet)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker) C:\Users\btejumola\Documents\MVACS_Code\Lesson03\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj HelloWorld

Comment: The code you've posted only has 329 characters in, so I suspect the problem is later than you've shown...

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx